# Make the enter key send message on iPad

Tags: ipad, messages

I use a Bluetooth keyboard with my iPad. When I am sending messages through the Messages app, the enter key does not initiate a "send" the way I expect (it, instead, just returns down to the next line). Is there a way to make the "enter" key send the message instead of dropping down to the next line? Some magic key combination perhaps?

Comment: I asked the same question, changing the keyboard settings doesn't work on the ipad (you're right cajunLuke) wonder why they didn't make that do that, its a bit annoying, as you are used to speed typing once you have the blue tooth ipad keyboard. Karen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On you iPad. Go into "**Settings**" then navigate to "**General**", go to "**Keyboard**" option. Select the "**International Keyboards**" option and change your "**Hardware Keyboard layout"** from "**U.S.**" to "**U.S.International-PC**". Your *RETURN/ENTER* Key will now send messages on you messaging Apps.

Comment: This does not work for me at all.  Does this really work for some?

Comment: Did not work for me either

Comment: Didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 3):

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> while <kbd>Cmd</kbd> is in action.

Comment: How do you do that on the iPad?  I don't see a COMMAND key

Comment: You'll have a "cmd" or "windows" key on your external keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a way to do that. The enter/return key does the same action as hitting the button in the lower-right of the keyboard. In some apps, it sends a message or performs an action; in others, it generates a newline. Messages does the latter. You have to use the Send button on the screen to send a message.

Comment: Where is the send button on the iPad?

Comment: The little arrow that appears next to the text field once you enter text.

Answer (score 0):

On a computer sometimes <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> is used for submitting content while <kbd>enter</kbd> is used for newlines. I doubt it is recognized by Messages on iPad but it's worth a try.

Comment: Command + Enter worked for me, don't know why that answer has a -2.

Comment: Same here. It worked for me

Comment: As of iOS 10 or maybe earlier, iPad supports pressing Return for Messages. But any other apps have to be programmed to accept it. It's not an automatic part of `UITextField` I guess.