# How do I send an iMessage on an iPad using an Apple Bluetooth Keyboard only?

Tags: ipad, keyboard, messages, bluetooth

I found [another question on this site](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56551/make-the-enter-key-send-message-on-ipad), with a similar problem, but doesn't seem to be answered. I'd like to be able to type an iMessage and hit "send" when using an Apple Bluetooth Keyboard and iPad Air without touching the screen. I've tried changing my hardware keyboard to International...without luck. I've used many combinations of shift or control or command or option and return/enter without luck. Looking for an answer, not a have-you-tried...scenario.

Comment: Here you go: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56551/make-the-enter-key-send-message-on-ipad